# не могу создать объект класса tkinter.font.Font

Tags: python, tkinter, шрифты

```
from tkinter.font import Font
f=Font(family='Monofur',size=32)
```

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'
```

Я не понимаю,о каком объекте NoneType может идти речь,в IDLE

```
>>> Font
<class 'tkinter.font.Font'>
```

ввод класса Font возвращает обычный подкласс tkinter.font

На сайтах с примерами кода,где я был,аналогичные куски кода работают исправно

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45705681/13970074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрим ошибку детально:

```
>>> from tkinter.font import Font                                               
>>> f = Font(family='Monofur', size=32)                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/font.py", line 93, in __init__
    tk.call("font", "create", self.name, *font)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'call'
```

`tk` - это объект главного окна, который берется или из глобальной переменной модуля tkinter, или передается первым параметром при создании объекта `Font` (см. [исходники](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0dd98c2d00a75efbec19c2ed942923981bc06683/Lib/tkinter/font.py#L69)).
Из-за того что окно еще не создано, значение этой переменной равно `None`, и при вызове метода `call` от `tk` возникает ошибка.

Нужно сначала создать объект `Tk()` (главное окно), потом уже создавать шрифт:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = Tk()
f = Font(family='Monofur', size=32)
# или f = Font(root, family='Monofur', size=32)
```